# Как передать данные в определенный инстанс класса?

Tags: java, android, ооп

Проект который я использую https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare.
Я создаю четыре экземпляра класса CheeseListFragment. Я не могу понять, как получить доступ к **конкретно третьему** экземпляру класса и передать данные?

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CheeseListFragment.OnDataPass {
     Adapter adapter;

...
      adapter = new Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

            for (int i=0; i<4; i++){
                adapter.addFragment(new CheeseListFragment(), items[i]);
            }
...

 viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                onDataPass(String.valueOf(position)); // Хочу отправить данные в третий инстанс CheeseListFragment 





     static class Adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitles = new ArrayList<>();



        public Adapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragments.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitles.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {


            return mFragments.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragments.size();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitles.get(position);
        }
    }
}






public class CheeseListFragment extends Fragment {

    List<News> lnews;
    private RecyclerViewAdapter mRecyclerviewAdapter;
    OnDataPass dataPasser;

...
    protected String[] mDataset;



    public interface OnDataPass {
        public void onDataPass(String data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity a) {
        super.onAttach(a);
        dataPasser = (OnDataPass) a;

    }
    public void passData(String data) 
        dataPasser.onDataPass(data);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас же в `Adapter` есть список фрагментов `mFragments`, берете из него нужный фрагмент и передаете в него данные.

Comment: Я хотел получить экземпляр и непосредственно в него передать в него данные. Пример конструкции Fragment fragment = adapter.getItem(2);                CheeseListFragment cheesyFragment = (CheeseListFragment) fragment; fragment.            cheesyFragment.onDataPass(...). Вот сюда как передать значение?

Comment: У вашего `cheesyFragment` есть метод `passData(String data) ` - его и вызывайте, в чем проблема то?